# Envers audit table creates a foreign key to and prevents deletion from another table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Here is my situation. 3 entities: Customer, Address, and CustomerAddress. I use Hibernate's schema builder to create my database tables (normal and audit).
Customer has a many-to-many relationship with Address and this relationship is defined by the CustomerAddress entity.

Customer class

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Customer implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   ...
   @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "customerId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK_CustomerToAddress_Customer"))
   private List<CustomerAddress> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Address Class

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Address implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
}
```

CustomerAddress Class

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "CustomerToAddress")
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name = "pk.customer",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")),
@AssociationOverride(name = "pk.address",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "addressId"))
})
public class CustomerAddress implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomerAddressId pk = new CustomerAddressId();
    ...
}
```

CustomerAddressId Class

```
public class CustomerAddressId implements Serializable
{
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
    ...
}
```

Now, when I create a Customer, an Address, and a CustomerAddress relationship it's all great until I try to perform a deletion. I can remove a CustomerAddress record just fine, but if I try to delete the linked Address record I get a Foreign Key violation error like this:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_NAME". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.CustomerToAddress_AUD", column 'addressId'.

So, the CustomerToAddress_AUD table has created a FK to the Address table and I will never be able to programmatically delete an Address using hibernate/JPA.

Any ideas on how to create an audited Many-To-Many relationship that won't prevent deletion of linked entities?

EDIT:
The code to export the schema is as follows:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
// set connection properties on config
config.configure();
SchemaExport sexport = new EnversSchemaGenerator(config).export();
sexport.execute(false, true, false, true); // args: script, export, justDrop, justCreate
```

Comment: How did you generate the schema? Envers shouldn't affect the "normal" schema in *any* way, so things like "the CustomerToAddress_AUD table has created a FK to the Address" should definitely not happen.

Comment: Updated question with relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: This definitely should not happen, looks like a bug, but no idea where. I'd report it in Hibernate's JIRA, sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem as of Hibernate 5.2.7.  I have created a JIRA [HHH-11463](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11463).

**UPDATE**

This is fixed as of 5.2.11.